# Stop the task in Spring Integration framework

Tags: spring, task, spring-integration

I would like to stop a KeepAliveReceiver task after a given event. I tested the following solutions and none is working 1) sending keepAliveReceiver.stop() to control but, 2) implement Lifecycle and call stop() 3) stop the scheduler. Any ideas how can I stop the task from within the running task?

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class KeepAliveReceiver implements Runnable, LifeCycle { 

private int limit;

@Autowired
private ControlBusGateway controlGateway; // sending messages to control Channel

@Autowired
private ThreadPoolTaskScheduler myScheduler;


@Override
public void run() {
    ...
    if ( event ) {
        LOGGER.debug( "FAILOVER! Starting messageReceiveRouter. ");

        controlGateway.send( new GenericMessage<String>( "@keepAliveReceiver.stop()" ) );
        // not allowed
        myScheduler.shutdown();
        // not working, the scheduler keeps starting the keepAliveReceiver          
        this.stop();
        //not working
    }   
}
@Override
public void stop() {
    LOGGER.debug( "STOPPED!");

}
```

and xml definition of the scheduler:

```
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10" />
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="keepAliveReceiver" method="run" fixed-rate="500" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Send to the **controlGateway** a Message with empty command ;-)
2. 'Kill' your `<control-bus>` and change it to

   `<outbound-channel-adapter channel="stopSchedulerChannel"   expression="@myScheduler.shutdown()">`
3. And add 
   `<channel id="stopSchedulerChannel">
   <dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
   </channel>`
4. And configure appropriate **executor** bean

Your problem is about a wish to stop task from himself. From other side `<control-bus>` allows operations only on `SmartLifecycle` implementors

Comment: I've changed my answer after further review. Sorry